# Unable to Scrape Span Text via XPath & WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I'm attempting to scrape the text:

> Eligible for free shipping with Amazon Prime

on [All Offers](https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0615797806/ref=olp_f_new?ie=UTF8&f_all=true&f_new=true) page of [this product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0615797806) using the following XPath:

```
.//*[@id='olpOfferList']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/i/span[contains(@class, '-')]
.//*[@id='olpOfferList']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/i/span
```

However, although both XPath match in Firebug they return an empty String in Selenium.

I'm using roughly the following code to scrape the text:

```
    try {
        String scrapedText = driver.findElement(By.xpath(XPath)).getText();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Edit:** For some reason the link on stackoverflow is not redirecting to 'All Offers" page (only to main product page). To view HTML on All Offers page please append the following:

```
/gp/offer-listing/0615797806/ref=olp_f_new?ie=UTF8&f_all=true&f_new=true   to   amazon.com
```

**Update:** Below is HTML snippet from page.

```
<div class="a-fixed-left-flipped-grid a-spacing-mini">
<div class="a-fixed-left-grid-inner" style="padding-left:170px">
<div id="olpOfferListColumn" class="a-fixed-left-grid-col a-col-right" style="padding-left:0%;width:100%;float:right;">
<div id="olpOfferList" class="a-section olpOfferList">
<div class="a-section a-padding-small">
<div class="a-section a-spacing-double-large" role="grid" aria-readonly="true" aria-label="More buying choices">
<div class="a-row a-spacing-mini" role="row">
<hr class="a-spacing-mini a-divider-normal"/>
<div class="a-row a-spacing-mini olpOffer" role="row">
<div class="a-column a-span2 olpPriceColumn" role="gridcell">
<span class="a-size-large a-color-price olpOfferPrice a-text-bold">                $10.79                </span>
<span class="supersaver">
<i class="a-icon a-icon-prime" aria-label="Eligible for free shipping with Amazon Prime.">
<span class="a-icon-alt">Eligible for free shipping with Amazon Prime.</span> // I want to scrape this text
</i>
</span>
<p class="olpShippingInfo">
</div>
<div class="a-column a-span3 olpConditionColumn" role="gridcell">
<div class="a-column a-span3 olpDeliveryColumn" role="gridcell">
<div class="a-column a-span2 olpSellerColumn" role="gridcell">
<div class="a-column a-span2 olpBuyColumn a-span-last" role="gridcell">
</div>
```

Comment: Update the question with relevant HTML.

Comment: try an xpath that actually makes sense and is not as expensive, i.e. avoid meaningless items in the middle: `//div[@id="olpOfferList"]//span[@class="supersaver"]/i/span`

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt to answer my own question with something that "gets the jobs done" but I am still looking for a better answer.

If instead of scraping via `getText()` I scrape via `getAttribute()` with the attribute `"textContent"` I'm able to successfully scrape the said content.

However, although this tech answers the question (or resolves the underlying issue) I am still looking for a way to do this directly using `getText()`  method so I consider this only a partial answer. I'm also trying to understand **why** my original code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared seems the *class* **supersaver** will be unique. So you can use the following line of code  :

```
String scrapedText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class="supersaver"]/i/span")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html there is one attribute `aria-label`, you can also find through it, using only one or two words to match, like `Eligible`  or `free shipping` to identify it.

```
//i[contains(@aria-label, 'free shipping')]
```